# Induced topology on a set by the image of open sets

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a topological space, $Y$ is a set, and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a map, when is possible to create a topology for $Y$ with the images of open sets in $X$? This is not always possible, because the image of any intersection of open sets is not the intersection of images, but there is some other condition in $f$ that makes it work?

What I know is that we can define a topology in $Y$ by the pre-images, exactly because they "preserve" intersections.